# App crashing when executed in OS X 10.7 environment

Tags: xcode, macos, crash-reports

I developped a MacOS application under XCode latest version, and am running OS X Mavericks 10.9.
One version of my app is compiled for OSX 10.7, and another one for 10.8 & 10.9.

People running under these 2 last OSes have no issue, when people running under OSX 10.7 have a crash upon startup.
I am not sure how the crash report can help me to understand what's going wrong.

Could someone help me to understand where the issue comes from or explain how I can simulate an execution under OSX 10.7 to see where it is crashing ?

```
Process:         MyAPP [37535]
Path:            /Applications/Utilities/MyAPP.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAPP
Identifier:      PS2F.MyAPP
Version:         15 (1)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [139]

Date/Time:       2014-08-28 12:19:44.107 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSView._layer
  Referenced from: /Applications/Utilities/MyAPP.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAPP
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Utilities/MyAPP.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAPP

Binary Images:
   0x10000e000 -        0x100034fff +PS2F.MyAPP (15 - 1) <A4548892-EFDE-367F-912F-3791E4EBEF21> /Applications/Utilities/MyAPP.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAPP
0x7fff5fc0e000 -     0x7fff5fc42baf  dyld (195.6 - ???) <C58DAD8A-4B00-3676-8637-93D6FDE73147> /usr/lib/dyld
0x7fff84843000 -     0x7fff8484efff  com.apple.CommonAuth (2.2 - 2.0) <4F5302A5-867A-3F2E-9E4B-98FA011678F8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/Versions/A/CommonAuth

[...]
```

Thanks.

Comment: `_OBJC_IVAR_$_NSView._layer`… this looks like a instance variable `_layer` of the class `NSView`. Do you access it directly? Maybe by accident?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symbol not found \_OBJC\_IVAR\_$\_NSView.\_layer (in AppKit) only on 10.7, works fine on 10.8 and 10.9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760465/symbol-not-found-objc-ivar-nsview-layer-in-appkit-only-on-10-7-works-fine)